# registration form for user

Tags: typo3

I am working on typo3 blank website & want to give registration & login form to user. So for this I install static_info_tables extension & study

http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/sr_feuser_register/2.5.9/view/1/5/ 
 tutorial.

But I am failed to provide registration & login form to user.

Please Help me & provide  proper documentation link regarding this topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very unclear question. What is that mean you 'failed to provide forms' ??

Comment: i means to say that login form is not visible. Please provide me needful help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem ......

Form is not visible as I did not include plugin in temlate file. We can define plugin like this:-

for login form:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    templateFile = typo3/sysext/felogin/template.html
    _CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE =
}
```

for registration form:

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1 {
    templateFile = typo3conf/ext/sr_feuser_register/pi1/tx_srfeuserregister_pi1_css_tmpl.html
    _CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE =
}
```

Also dont forget to include FE User Registration CSS-styled in your typoscript template